# Error installing Gearman on Alpine Linux

Tags: linux, php, alpine-linux

I've tried to install Gearman from source on Alpine, but it's gives an error:

> configure: error: Please install libgearman

I tried to `apk search libgearman`, with no result, but in Ubuntu there is `libgearman-dev` and in CentOS `libgearman-devel`.

Then I tried to install Gearman using the command `pecl install gearman`, but it's gives the same result.

Note: I'm using php56 on latest Alpine container.

Is there any workaround that I'm missing?

Comment: have you tried `apk add gearman-dev`?

Comment: when i try to install gearman-dev, it's gives error result --> # apk add gearman-dev
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  gearman-dev (missing):
    required by: world[gearman-dev]
/ #

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gearman is currently only available in the `edge/testing` repository, which is considered experimental, but may be enough for your needs (see [here](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=gearman*&branch=edge&arch=x86_64) for package details and availability).

For installing Gearman, add the `edge` repositories to your `/etc/apk/repositories` file and update your apk database:

```
echo http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main >> /etc/apk/repositories  
echo http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community >> /etc/apk/repositories  
echo http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing >> /etc/apk/repositories
apk update
```

Then, install the Gearman packages with:

```
apk add gearman-dev gearman-libs
```